# if a simple pendulum is dropped in a elevator with a acceleration greater than acceleration due to gravity then what will be its frequency

Tags: classical-mechanics

if a simple pendulum is dropped in a elevator with a acceleration greater than  acceleration due to gravity then what will be its frequency ? We know time period depends on frequency.

Comment: How can we **drop** pendulum with more than $g$ acceleration?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that the elevator is "dropped", with a small rocket on the elevator roof (thrusting downward)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same formula as usual but with the difference that. $$ g\rightarrow g\pm g'$$ where $g'$ is the acceleration of the elevator. The plus sign is used if the two accelerations are in different directions... Thus if elevator free fall then $g-g'=0 $ and the period goes to infinity.